# Ionic 5 Capacitor livereload white screen after re-build

Tags: ionic-framework

I'm struggling since days with the livereload functionality on my Ionic 5 / Capacitor app. I get on the simulator a white screen after the build is reload, i.e. after a change in the code. When I run the app first time under command "ionic capacitor run ios -l" the app loads perfect in the iOS simulator. After a change in the code I see on CLI that this was compiled successfully. However, in the simulator I stuck on a white screen. I tried many solutions indicated on the web, still having this issue. Is this a known bug on Ionic 5 using capacitor or do you have any idea what could help?

My capacitor config file looks like this:

```
  appId: 'xxxx',
  appName: 'xxxx',
  webDir: 'www',
  bundledWebRuntime: false,
  cordova: {
    preferences: {
      scheme: 'app',
      hostname: 'localhost',
      ScrollEnabled: 'false',
      BackupWebStorage: 'none',
      AutoHideSplashScreen: 'false',
      SplashMaintainAspectRatio: 'true',
      FadeSplashScreenDuration: '200',
      SplashShowOnlyFirstTime: 'false',
      SplashScreen: 'screen',
      SplashScreenDelay: '1000',
      loadUrlTimeoutValue: '70000',
      ShowSplashScreenSpinner: 'false',
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: White screen usually means that the app crashed. Can you see the Android / iOS logs?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I had to put this project on the side. Looks like that now everything is working smoothly and the reload is happening after code changes. Might be that the issue was more on my Mac.

Answer (score -2):

this worked for me:

***Option 1***: Turn off your VPN if you are using a VPN either on your desktop or your mobile or even both of them.

***Option 2***: Turn off your windows firewall.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).